# Read every fourth line from a text file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

So, I have a text file with the following:

> Andrew Law
>   0276376352
>   13 Parsons St
>   Kevin Kyle
>   0376458374
>   29 Penrod Drive
>   Billy Madison
>   06756355
>   16 Stafford Street

Now on my Form, I have a ListBox. When the Form loads, I would like to read every fourth line from the text file (every name) and display it in the ListBox.

All I have right now is the following:

```
Dim People As String
People = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filelocation")(3)
ListBox1.Items.Add(People)
```

This however only reads line number 4 where as I want to read EVERY fourth line after that also.

Comment: You have to give it a try, and then we'll be able to help if you don't succeed.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  How are you reading the file?  In the code which reads the file, how do you think you may be able to skip lines?

Comment: All i have at the moment is: ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(filelocation)) I am very new to VB.net i assume i need to create a loop?

Comment: I now have the following:

Dim People As String
People = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filelocation")(3)
ListBox1.Items.Add(People)

This however only reads line number 4 where as i want to read EVERY fourth line after that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the strings extracted from a source file, when the current line is a multiple of a pre-defined number of lines to skip or `0`, to a ListBox and allow a user to select a Name from the list to fill some Labels with the details related to the selected Name.

- Parse and extract the People Names from the array of string. Each Name can be found at an index which is multiple of the value specified by the `skipLines` field.
- Add each Name to a ListBox control.
- When a Name is selected from the ListBox list of names, add the related details to some Labels (named **`lblPhoneNumber`** and **`lblAddress`** here). To identify the correct informations in the array, we're using the **`skipLines`** value as a multiplier this time. This way, even if you add some more details in the list of names, you'll find the right informations modifying just the `skipLines` value.
  You need to subscribe to the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged) event of the ListBox:

---

```
Public Class Form1
    Private people As String()
    Private skipLines As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        skipLines = 3
        people = File.ReadAllLines([Source File])
        For line As Integer = 0 To people.Length - 1
            If line Mod skipLines = 0 Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(people(line))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim StartIndex As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex * skipLines
        lblPhoneNumber.Text = people(StartIndex + 1)
        lblAddress.Text = people(StartIndex + 2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**How this works**:

Define the number of lines to skip. We want a line of text, then skip 3 lines, here:

```
Dim skipLines As Integer = 3
```

We create an array of strings. It will contain the output of [File.ReadAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines), which of course returns an array of strings:

```
Dim people As String() = File.ReadAllLines([Source File])
```

Iterate the whole content of the array of strings, line by line. A collection enumeration starts from `0`, so we parse the list from `0` to the number of elements `- 1`:

```
For line As Integer = 0 To people.Length - 1
'[...]
Next
```

The `If` condition if met when the current line number is a multiple of `skipLines`.
The [Mod operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator) divides two numbers and returns the remainder of the operation. If there's no reminder, the `line` number is a multiple of `skipLines`, the number of lines we want to skip.

```
If line Mod skipLines = 0 Then
`[...]
End If
```

Finally, when the condition is met, add the content of the array of strings (the **`people`** array) at the index represented by the current **`line`** value, to the `ListBox.Items` collection:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(people(line))
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Would you mind explaining exactly what each line of code does? Obviously i'm an absolute newbie so would really help :-)

Comment: What i would also like is to have different labels on the form and when the user clicks on one of the names in the listbox the labels each show the corresponding details. 
For example if the user selects "Andrew Law" one of the labels will read his phone number and the other label will read his address. Any idea how i would go about achieving this?

Comment: Since the index of each name on the list can be multiplied by the number of the lines skipped (`skipLines`), you can use the multiplier to access the source array of string (`people`). I'll make an edit, to show how you could do this.

Comment: Thank you for that, really appreciate it. It runs fine however for some reason the labels aren't changing. Where abouts do you suggest i declare the variables? Im wondering if i have them in the wrong place and this is the issue.

Comment: Maybe you haven't subscribed to the `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event. `people` and `skipLines` must become `Fields`, declared in the Form class scope. I'll make an edit to explain that better.

Comment: Sorry i am still a little confused on how to "subscribe to the Listbox.SelectedIndexChanged event".  Exactly how do i declare people and skiplines as fields? I have copied the code exactly, and it runs fine, but the labels still aren't changing.

Comment: In the Form designer, select your ListBox. In the Properties panel, click on the lightning bolt button. This will show the public events of the control. Find the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and double-click on it (on the name). This will create an Event Handler inside the code window for you. Insert the related code there.

Comment: Okay sorry yes i already have the related code there however for some reason the labels text still arent changing.

Comment: Is it possible at all for you to help me with one final thing? I would just like the user to be able to click the labels, which displays an input box. There, they can change the values (for example change street address) and this will also modify the text file.

Comment: Too broad to answer here. You'll have to post another question for that. Possibly specifying all the *problems*/ *requirements* you have in one go. Remember to show what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much i really appreciate all the help, very happy! Have a great day and thanks again :-)